# Does communication through UDP Port 137 always mean there is a port scan done on the host?

Tags: networking

If a computer is communicating with another through UDP port 137, can we assume that it is a host port scan? If YES, how can we identify that and stop it from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot assume all UDP/137 traffic is a port-scan; that could be legitimate [NetBios over TCP/IP traffic](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380015%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

I have a corporate laptop from my employer, and I am unconnected to the corporate network behind my home firewall.   Just over the last hour alone, I have seen over 1000 NBT packets... why?  Because windows is broadcasting NBT name queries for a windows domain controller, printers, SMS resources, etc...

[image: NBT Traffic]